# note Common options

Tags: command-line

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and currently learning command line.

When I type in `info rm`, a paragraphs says "Also see *note Common options::."

How and where can I see "note Common options" ?

Comment: It should be a hyperlink - place the cursor anywhere in the underlined text and press "Enter"

Comment: Unlike `man` pages, in `info` pages you can use the cursor keys to move the cursor around the screen. As @steeldriver says, move the cursor over the link and press "Enter". You can also type `info common options:` (you need the last : or it takes you somewhere else!)

Comment: Thank you both ! I tried and it works !